# bash adds apostrophes to expanded variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, variable-substitution

I am reading in a file inside my bash script where each line consists of multiple columns like this:

```
ANSIBLE 'first run' '--diff --extra-vars "client=yes fast=no"'
```

As you can see, the line consists of three columns, the ones with whitespaces in apostrophes. The third column contain options for a binary to call. As I read in the file, I stored those options to a variable:

```
custom_options=${columns[2]}
```

This evaluates to

```
custom_options='--diff --extra-vars "client=yes fast=no"'
```

Now I want to execute my binary with those options:

```
ansible-playbook $custom_options site.yml
```

However this fails, because on execution there were added apostrophes around the inner string:

```
ansible-playbook --diff --extra-vars '"client=yes fast=no"' site.yml
```

Does anybody know how to substitute the variable string as-is?

Here is a short script to quickly reproduce the behavior:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
touch "as is"
command='-name "as is"'
find . $command -type f
```

Comment: This is [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Bash isn't adding any quotes. That's its way of printing out the command when it would be visually ambiguous — bash is saying that `"client=yes fast=no"` is one argument, starting and ending with double quotes.

Comment: See our reference question: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround rather than a solution. I surrounded the whole command with the variable inside an `eval` expression:

```
eval "ansible-playbook $custom_options site.yml"
```

Here the equivalent usage within the example script:

```
...
eval "find . $command -type f"
```

I am no bash guru and I don't know if this workaround has any side effects. Nevertheless I tested following:

- eval works with pipes: `eval "command | tee file"`
- quotes inside eval are possible: `eval "command \"${var}\""`

However it fit my needs but it feels dirty. Better solutions are welcome.

Comment: That's the (well, a) right solution. It does mean you need to be very careful about what you put in the `custom_options` variable.

Comment: Of course @Gilles `custom_options` should be parsed for valid content before usage, to avoid injection points for malicious code. Good hint.